# Do I need to worry about SQL injections when using dplyr in R to import csv into SQLite database?

Tags: r, sqlite, dplyr

I have a database in R that uses RSQLite. There is one table in this database, and I want the user to be able to import .csv files to add data to that table. If I'm using dplyr to do this, do I need to worry about 'cleaning' the data in the spreadsheet to make sure none of it is going to screw with my database? Like, for example, making sure apostrophes don't interfere with the SQL query. Does dplyr take care of this? I am not very familiar with SQL so please bear with me.

Comment: from https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/build_sql.html : "This is a convenience function that should prevent sql injection attacks (which in the context of dplyr are most likely to be accidental not deliberate) by automatically escaping all expressions in the input, while treating bare strings as sql. This is unlikely to prevent any serious attack, but should make it unlikely that you produce invalid sql.". So I would expect that some effort has been made to secure the package's functions, at least from accidental issues.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper So if there were apostrophes in some cells in the csv file I'm importing, they wouldn't cause any issues if I use `build_sql`?

Comment: I don't think you should use `build_sql`, I mean that the authors did think about SQL injections, so I don't think you're likely to run into any issue by feeding the wrong string to dplyr functions, but I don't know for sure, hence it's a comment not an answer :).

Comment: If it's a literal insert (lacking, perhaps, an `id` field in the database table), then the use of `DBI::dbWriteTable` *should* be safe. (The drivers that I've briefly looked at are using bound-parameters, which is I believe safe.)

Comment: but `dplyr` / `dbplyr` don't have any tools to write to DB as far as I know, so you might actually be refering to `DBI` functions as r2evans implies

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper ah ok I see what you mean. Yeah that makes sense. Yeah I think you're right, I must be thinking of DBI. Thank you r2evans

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be safe as long as you used parametrized statements in `RSQLite` (dplyr has nothing to do with this), i.e. the potentially dangerous data are set as separated argument and not put directly in the query text. RSQLite is going to make sure the values are properly escaped to avoid SQL injections.

The [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/vignettes/RSQLite.html) provides examples of such queries, here with a `delete` action, but it is transposable to insertion.

```
rs <- dbSendStatement(mydb, 'DELETE FROM iris WHERE "Sepal.Length" < :x')

## added: bind the actual data here:
dbBind(rs, param = list(x = 4.5))

dbGetRowsAffected(rs)
```

Comment: Sorry to sound so ignorant, so you're saying that the importing of the .csv is fine, even if there are apostrophes or something in the acutal text in some of the cells in the .csv file, but when I am handling that data inside the app, to use parameterized statements to prevent that potentially 'dangerous' text from causing any issues?

Comment: I am not sur about how exactly you are importing your csv, but as long as the function that takes care of creating the INSERT query of each row uses parametrized statements as mentionned in the above answer, then yes, even if there are apostrophes or any other character that might have been interpreted as SQL code, these characters are going to be escaped and safely stored, and you do not need to worry about sql injections.